# Running Selenium 2.0 tests on a test web server

Tags: c#, selenium

I've got a bunch of web (integration) tests, that are coded in C# as nunit tests, using the `Selenium.WebDriver` nuget package which means I can run them from my test runner - I don't need to a selenium server or anything, they just work on my dev machine.

I want to get these tests to run on our test server, triggered from our build server (which happens to be team city but I don't think that's relevant).

So... How can I do this? Because these tests are wrapped up as c# unit tests, is the only way I'm going to be able to run them to install nunit on the test server, and run nunit against the tests, or does selenium support another way?

Thanks

Comment: Most CI solutions like TeamCity, Jenkins, Hudson, TFS and CC.Net all support this right out the bat. What exact bit is confusing you? I get what you are trying to do but I don't really understand what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

We used jenkins, but we installed nunit and have it let the tests run then. I do not think that the selenium server setup would work without nunit or having these tests additional in an non-c# format.